# Find $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2+3}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Solve $$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)}\frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2 + 3}$$

I can't use l'hopital's rule to solve this limit because the numerator and denominator don't create an indeterminate form. How do I solve/approach this limit?

Comment: I don't see what's stopping you from plugging in directly the values. You get $0/(0+3) = 0$. I could be wrong though.

Comment: oh wow you have a point thank you :)

Comment: I don't see it as indeterminate form it's simply 0

Comment: Let $I$ be the limit in the question. Set $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ when $r$ tends to zero. Hence you get $I=\lim_r \to 0 \frac{r^2 \cos(\theta) \sin(\theta)}{ r^2+3}$ which results that the limit tends to zero and the value of the limit ($0$) is **independent of $\theta$** and because of this $I$ has limit and its value is equal to zero.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is $0$. Directly evaluating $(x,y)=(0,0)$ forms

$$\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)}\frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2 + 3}=\frac{0}{3}=0$$

Alternatively, as mentioned in the comments, you could convert to polar coordinates and let $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. Then

$$\lim_{r \to 0}\frac{r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta}{r^2 + 3}=\frac{0}{3}=0$$

---

Though it isn't part of your question, I also found that the function is continuous at $(0,0)$. Suppose

$$f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2+3}$$

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. We need to a find a $\delta > 0$ such that if  $0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$ then $|f(x,y)−0|< \varepsilon$. Let $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ and suppose that $0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$. Then using the fact that $x\le x^2+y^2+3$, i.e. $$\left| \frac{x}{x^2+y^2+3}\right|\le 1$$ we have

$$|f(x,y)−0|=\left|\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2+3} \right|=\left|\frac{x}{x^2+y^2+3} \right||y|\le |y|\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le \delta=\frac{\varepsilon}{2}< \varepsilon$$

Hence, $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$. Therefore, $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2+3}=f(0,0)=0$.